Creating a Material3 Settings Page in Android
I am new to Android Development.
I am creating a settings page in Android Studio.
But the problem is if I want to toggle a setting for example theme, then I have to click on the Button saying theme. I want to make it like a list so that wherever I click near the "App Theme" preference it toggles the button. I'm not sure how to fix this. Could somebody please take a look?
My Settings pageSettings page
The Settings.xml code is
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Settings">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutLargeStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumSize">

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    app:title="Settings"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/text_size"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="0dp" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Appearance"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/settings_preferences_layout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/settings_preferences"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"
            android:text="App Theme"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button"
            android:text="System"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/settings_preferences_layout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/settings_preferences"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Material You" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.divider.MaterialDivider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:dividerInsetStart="16dp"
        app:dividerInsetEnd="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>


Add a click listener on the FrameLayout that toggles the switch. Also, why don't you just use Preferences instead of re-inventing this wheel?

@dominicoder
As mentioned I am new to Android Development.
I have tried using preferences before and had a bad experience, are they customizable this far and can I use material 3 Ui in Preferences?

I don't know but a quick web search would indicate you can with some work.
